# Can a game that previously did not have trading cards begin offering trading cards?

Tags: steam-trading-cards

I notice one of the games I'm looking forward to does not offer Steam Trading Cards as one of its features.  This is quite unfortunate, but before I lose hope, even after a game goes onto the Steam Store, can it still offer trading cards at some point in the future?

Note: I am not asking if a specific game WILL offer trading cards, as that would be up to the developer.  I am asking if it is possible for a game to offer them if it did not upon initial release.

Comment: I don't know since when you followed the trading cards, but there were only five games in the beginning and nearly every week there are more. There are probably more games that got cards added later than games that had them since their release.

Comment: I think the new "Tomb Raider" and "Metro 2033" haven't had cards when they released,they added them soon after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it happens all the time. In fact, because Trading Cards haven't been around for very long, the majority of games that now have them are games that didn't have them at first, either because they came out before the feature was added, or because the cards/backgrounds/etc. weren't ready/planned yet when the game was released.

A note: Since the cards are given based on time played, this doesn't require an update to the game at all. It's mostly a matter of creating the artwork/descriptions/emoticons for it.